# Heroku Discord Bot is offline

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm hosting a discord chat bot on heroku, and suddenly it went offline. I am new to hosting on heroku, so i don't understand a lot, but, i tried simple things like deploying a branch again (im connected to github), and that wouldn't work.

**Edit:**
Here is the log:

Before i click open app:

> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.265702+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>
> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.265704+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>
> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.265705+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>
> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.265707+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
>
> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.327613+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>
> 2018-07-23T16:54:27.310511+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

After clicking Open App:

> 2018-07-23T16:58:44.866697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=cratefield.herokuapp.com request_id=b32a5f7d-157e-45a5-805b-8c306140d020 fwd="73.23.238.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-07-23T16:58:45.502353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cratefield.herokuapp.com request_id=19e6fc48-37ed-48db-87f9-759d704ddb3e fwd="73.23.238.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-07-23T16:58:45.552383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cratefield.herokuapp.com request_id=bba2456f-50bc-4dbb-bee2-50b36a8caef5 fwd="73.23.238.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-07-23T17:01:47.069331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=cratefield.herokuapp.com request_id=9a098d43-bc46-403a-9ed3-5b701cd720ac fwd="73.23.238.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Are you using heroku's free plan?

Comment: Rodrigo Mata yes

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer

Comment: From your edit looks like your application crashes after booting. Have you installed all the required dependencies? Does your node version matches Heroku's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That happens because you're using a `web` dyno: a dyno that is put asleep if the application doesn't serve a website for more than 1 hour.
The solution is to switch from a `web` dyno to a `worker` dyno: this type does not serve websites (and if you're running a Discord bot you don't need it) and never goes to sleep.

Go in your `Procfile` file & replace `web` with `worker`, it should look like this:

```
worker: npm start //this is the command you use to start your app.
```

If you want you can take a look at the [Heroku article about sleeping apps](https://blog.heroku.com/app_sleeping_on_heroku).

Comment: I've already done that, but i am using `worker: node bot.js`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Make sure you're using that dyno type by going in the "Resources" tab & activating the worker (click on the pencil & then on the button, if it's gray, it means it's selected)

Comment: I've made sure of that, but again, i have `web` disabled.

Comment: According to Heroku, this should never happen. If you have web disabled & worker enabled, can you please post what does the console log?

Comment: You're having two different errors: the first one is your application crashing by itself (it's a problem from your code), the other one is from heroku. If you don't have a web app, you can't access its website (that's what "Open app" does). If you want to restart your app, click on "More" > "Restart all dynos"

Comment: Would restarting my app make it wake up?

Comment: At the moment it's not sleeping, it crashed. If you restart it, it will probably crash again because of something in your code. Since you're using a worker dyno your app cannot sleep

Comment: Federico Grandi if i put my code in my question would you be able to find an error? I've spent like 20 minutes trying to fix it.

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 4):

I know it's one year late but for those who are still having this issue, you have a limit of 550 hours per month (about 22 days) to host your bot with the free plan (paid plans get no run time limit)

This might be the problem, you can check your notifications on heroku to find out.

Comment: While this is true, you can add a credit card to your account, to receive 450 extra free hours per month, resulting in being able to run 1 free dyno for the whole month.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your bot is that [Heroku's free plan](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) makes your application to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. The solution would be to select a paid plan to be sure that your bot remains active at all times.

Comment: How would you wake it up?

Comment: A workaround would be to set a cron tu run every 28 minutes and to interact in some way with your bot

Comment: I'm on windows. How would i create a cron to do something on heroku? or would it be discord?

AND HOW DO I WAKE IT UP AFTER IT IS ASLEEP

Comment: Setting a cron is out of scope of the question, you can google it. And for waking it up you just need to interact with your chat bot, but after going to sleep, it needs to start the dyno, which would take like 2 or 3 minutes before you get a response. Here's a [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping) for Heroku's related documentation

Comment: I've been trying to talk to it for about 15 minutes now, with no response.