# discord bot offline in production not in local

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

i have created a simple [discord bot](https://github.com/sahasrara62/discord_bot/tree/discord_bot_deploy) using python and deployed it on Heroku free instance.

so whenever I deployed the bot in Heroku and then add the bot in a new server and send a message it replies for some time and then automatically goes offline.

To solve the issue, I deployed the bot on my machine connected to the Heroku database, and it is working fine here and the bot is not going offline.

I am new to this discord bot and Heroku and couldn't figure out why this is happening.

i followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483462/heroku-discord-bot-is-offline) still no solved, as deployment message is saying it is sucessfully deployed but bot is offline.
Thanks

logs

```
2020-09-25T07:57:02.239139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-25T07:57:02.257368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-25T07:57:02.339933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-25T07:57:02.378370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-25T07:57:02.380707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-25T07:57:06.444215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py`
2020-09-25T07:57:11.482276+00:00 app[web.1]: Logged on as prashant_bot#9323!
2020-09-25T07:57:41.039923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=still-sierra-90196.herokuapp.com request_id=27691bf0-ab4e-49c2-8b37-39a87a64c3bd fwd="103.79.97.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-25T07:58:06.676326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-25T07:58:06.694541+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-25T07:58:06.786955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-25T07:58:06.817777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-25T07:58:09.050473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-sierra-90196.herokuapp.com request_id=5ae96361-aa32-4c5c-a53e-f8b213cc3afa fwd="103.79.97.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: post the heroku log. Your `Procfile` defines your heroku process as a `web` process. The error you are probably running into is failure to bind to $PORT. Change that `web` to anything but that e.g. `worker` or `bot`.

Comment: @TinNguyen, i added thwe log with changing web to worker still it crashed

Comment: the log shows you are still executing it as a `web`. The error also says what I assumed `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Comment: @TinNguyen sorry i think, i had show you the logs from previous build.

Answer (score 0):

it's working now, here the changes what i have made in `Procfile`

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
heroku ps:scale worker=1
worker: python app.py
```

also in heroku application dashboard, i had updated the dynos. so think help me.

Also thanks to @TinNguyen for his help :) .

[image]